# How to install iptables-legacy on RHEL8

Tags: iptables, rhel8, dnf

I want to install this package for iptables-legacy on my RHEL 8 instance: https://fedora.pkgs.org/rawhide/fedora-aarch64/iptables-legacy-1.8.8-3.fc37.aarch64.rpm.html

When I do `dnf install iptables-legacy` , it returns an error saying the package can't be found.

I guess I need to add a new repository ( https://fedora.pkgs.org/rawhide/fedora-aarch64), using `dnf install` ... but not sure how to get the details of this repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora 28 is RHEL 8 upstream per:  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/fedora-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux/index.html

To install iptables v1.6.2

```
microdnf update && microdnf install -y dnf
dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/i/iptables-libs-1.6.2-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm
dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/i/iptables-1.6.2-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm
```